# Manually trigger kubernetes cronjob fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

My k8s version:

```
    kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.2", GitCommit:"8b5a19147530eaac9476b0ab82980b4088bbc1b2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:38:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.7-eks-d88609", GitCommit:"d886092805d5cc3a47ed5cf0c43de38ce442dfcb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-31T00:29:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.20) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

My cronjob file:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    app: git-updater
  name: git-updater
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Replace
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: git-updater
          name: git-updater
        spec:
          containers:
          - args:
            - sh
            - -c
            - apk add --no-cache git openssh-client && cd /repos && ls -d */*.git/
              | while read dir; do cd /repos/$dir; git gc; git fetch --prune; done
            image: alpine
            name: updater
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: test
              name: test
            - mountPath: test
              name: test
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
          - persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: pvc
            name: repos
  schedule: '@daily'
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 4

...
```

When I create the job from file, all goes well:

```
kubectl -n my-ns create -f git-updater.yaml
cronjob.batch/git-updater created
```

But I would like to trigger it manually just for testing purposes, so I do:

```
kubectl -n my-ns create job --from=cronjob/git-updater test-job
error: unknown object type *v1beta1.CronJob
```

Which is strange because I have just been able to create it from file.
In another similar post it was suggested to switch from ApiVersion `v1beta1` to `v1`.... but when I do so then I get:

```
 kubectl -n my-ns create -f git-updater.yaml
error: unable to recognize "git-updater.yaml": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1"
```

I am a little stuck here, how can I test my newly and successfully created CronJob?

Answer (score 4):

That's your **v1.20** cluster version, that doing that.
Short answer is you should **upgrade cluster to 1.21**, where cronjobs works more or less stable.

Check

1. [no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520866/no-matches-for-kind-cronjob-in-version-batch-v1(https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521713/9929015)) , especially comment

> One thing is the api-version, another one is in which version the
> resource you are creating is available. By version 1.19.x you do have
> batch/v1 as an available api-resource, but you don't have the resource
> CronJob under it.

2. [Kubernetes Create Job from Cronjob not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902379/9929015)

---

I have an 1.20.9 GKE cluster and face the same issue as you

```
$kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.2", GitCommit:"8b5a19147530eaac9476b0ab82980b4088bbc1b2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:38:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.9-gke.1001", GitCommit:"1fe18c314ed577f6047d2712a9d1c8e498e22381", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-23T23:06:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.13b5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.20) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1

cronjob.batch/git-updater created

$kubectl -n my-ns create job --from=cronjob/git-updater test-job
error: unknown object type *v1beta1.CronJob
```

---

At the same time, your `cronjob` yaml perfectly works with `apiVersion: batch/v1` on **1.21** GKE one.

```
$kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.2", GitCommit:"8b5a19147530eaac9476b0ab82980b4088bbc1b2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:38:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3-gke.2001", GitCommit:"77cdf52c2a4e6c1bbd8ae4cd75c864e9abf4c79e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-20T18:38:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6b7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


$kubectl -n my-ns create -f cronjob.yaml
cronjob.batch/git-updater created
$ kubectl -n my-ns create job --from=cronjob/git-updater test-job
job.batch/test-job created

$kubectl describe job test-job -n my-ns
Name:           test-job
Namespace:      my-ns
Selector:       controller-uid=ef8ab972-cff1-4889-ae11-60c67a374660
Labels:         app=git-updater
                controller-uid=ef8ab972-cff1-4889-ae11-60c67a374660
                job-name=test-job
Annotations:    cronjob.kubernetes.io/instantiate: manual
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Tue, 02 Nov 2021 17:54:38 +0000
Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
...
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  16m   job-controller  Created pod: test-job-vcxx9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use k9s tool to trigger k8s cronjob, some k9s version may fail to execute and will return this error.

Try to update the k9s tool [to the latest version](https://github.com/derailed/k9s/releases).